# Font unusable in Lotus Notes

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, fonts, lotus-notes

I use Lotus Notes 8.5 on Win7, and my colleagues use Lotus Notes 4.6 on XP. They use a font FangSong_GB2312 which comes with XP but not with Win7. To fix compatibility issues, I installed Lotus Notes 4.6 on Win7, and copied the font from XP into Windows\Fonts directory. But in Lotus Notes 4.6 I can't see or set the font, while in some other applications I can.

Whats's worse, I found the font was somehow lost in my notebook with XP from which I copied it. After I copied it back, In Lotus Notes 4.6 on the notebook I can't see or set the font either (Previously I can). Now I have two computers, on neither Lotus Notes 4.6 works with FangSong_GB2312.

I've tried rebooting and reinstalling Lotus Notes 4.6 with no luck. Does anyone have a clue what could cause the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last Time I had to do with 4.6 was 18 years ago (yes, that's how old Notes 4.6 is), but if I remember correctly, then the list of fonts in 4.6 was limited to a maximum number. I just googled and found the limit of 250 fonts that 4.6 can display.

In [this article](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/comp.groupware.lotus-notes.misc/6vg1xMqMLl4) there is an explanation for that, I just paste the relevant information here:

> Notes R4.x uses an 8-bit indexing ID to build a table of available fonts on the system, allowing Notes to
>   index up to 250 fonts.  This 250 font indexing limit is a current limitation of Notes.   An enhancement
>   request has been submitted to Lotus Quality Engineering to expand the number of fonts Notes is capable of
>   indexing.
>
> Since the font table that Notes builds is highly dependent on the operating system font ID assignments, there
>   is no clear pattern to which fonts will be included in Notes.  The current recommendation is to use a Font
>   Manager such as Adobe Type Manager on each machine to partially control the indexing order of fonts.  The
>   customer should reduce the number of fonts in the system folder (either Macintosh or Windows) to include only
>   standard fonts.  The customer should only use these fonts when designing views in Notes.  Additional fonts
>   may be activated by a Font Manager.  With this approach, all system fonts will be indexed first, and
>   therefore, any fonts used in a Notes View should be available.

Comment: Thank you! Someone gave an idea at last! 1. There should be few fonts on the notebook which were installed by the user, if there actually were. (Since I'm not at work, I can't check it now.) Almost all of the fonts come with XP. Could their number excceed 250?

Comment: 2. What's a font ID? Is it a name under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts? If so, I can save the effort figuring out how to download and use Adobe Type Manager.

Comment: 3. If I somehow altered the font ID, how could I make Lotus Notes rebuild the font table? Should I reinstall it?

Comment: As I said: I just googled the answer... I can not answer your additional questions... How about google it yourself? There are enough search phrases / etc. In the linked article to find out yourself...

Comment: Thank you. I played with Adobe Type Manager Deluxe, and somehow solved the problem. However, the font in IE is disturbed too...